# matplotlib.image.imsave TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror

Simplest fail case:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
path = 'test_images/input.jpg'
temp = mpimg.imread(path)
mpimg.imsave(temp, 'output.jpg')
```

I get:

```
line 1347, in imsave
image.set_data(arr)
File "/Users/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", 
line 600, in set_data
raise TypeError("Image data cannot be converted to float")
```

I have tested that the file exists (putting the above code in a if os.path.isfile(path): test) and printed the temp.shape which gives me the expected results. Be grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a mismatch in arguments.

`mpimg.imsave(temp, 'output.jpg')` instead try,

```
mpimg.imsave('output.jpg', temp)
```

Documentation here. [imsave](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html?highlight=imshow#skimage.io.imsave)

Comment: Thanks, could have sworn I'd double checked this. I'm fairly new to python and wasn't aware that so little checking is done on parameters.